# Splitting strings properly in Python 3

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, split

I have to read in data line by line from a website. The first line of the website reads:

Take out the garbage, 5, May 8

I want to put this into a list with "Take out the garbage" separated from the "5" separated from the "May 8"

I am given this code to use:

```
 def readHtml():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("#website")
    html = response.readline()
    data = html.decode('utf-8').split()
```

and I wanted to split it at the commas so that there would be no commas in the list so I added this after 'split' in the last line:

```
    data = html.decode('utf-8').split(',')
```

However when I try to print this it reads:

```
['Take out the garbage', ' 5', ' May 8\n']
```

with the weird \n after May 8 and strange spacing before May and before 5.

Comment: You just have to `html.strip("\n")`

Comment: where would I put that in my code though?

Comment: That's a bit harsh.  @Lia, you can use `strip("\n")` on a string anytime, but it's probably best before you split it.

Comment: @pylan I got it! Thanks so much for your help